# LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c, linker, c++-cli, extern

I have a **sample.c** file where a non-static function is defined

Source: sample.c

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

int get_sample_value()
{
    return 1000;
}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

There is pure **C++** SDK project, **sample_sdk** which basically generates a couple of static-libs, where *get_sample_value()* function is used within one of the source files as follows:

Source: sample_sdk_source.cpp

```
extern int get_sample_value();

static void do_processing()
{
    int sample_value = get_sample_value();
    process( sample_value );
}
```

Above-mentioned **sample.c** will be compiled in another **C++/CLI** GUI application, **SampleViewer** where **sample_sdk** libs are included within this application.
But when compiling the SampleViewer we are getting the following error:

> libsample-sdk-x86.lib(sample_sdk_source.obj) : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl get_sample_value()"
>   (?get_sample_value@@YAPBUint@@XZ)  referenced in function "public:
>   static void __cdecl do_processing()" (?do_processing@@SAXXZ)

I also tried to use the same function from SampleViewer::main.cpp file, but the same error exists.
Is there any issue when accessing function defined in C file as extern from C++/CLI environment?

Comment: You should declare the function in a header and include the header in both source files, though what you’ve written will work. You need to link both the object files too; that’s probably your principal problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the answer, but there were some technical issues for introducing a common header.

Comment: Work out how to resolve those technical issues — any real size program needs headers.  You can't afford to repeat code (such as the function declaration) across files — it becomes a maintenance nightmare very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker error says it all:

- Your `extern int get_sample_value();` declaration in C++ sets up an undefined symbol for the *mangled* name `?get_sample_value@@YAPBUint@@XZ`
- Your definition in sample.c defines a symbol with a non-mangled name (`_get_sample_value`).

To solve this, either mark your declaration in C++ with `extern "C"` as well, or better yet: move the declaration into a header that both sample.c and sample_sdk_source.cpp can include (with the `#if defined(__cplusplus)` guard)

Comment: I moved the declaration to extern "C" block, and it works fine.